# Подсветка определенных слов в shell PuTTy

Tags: bash, shell, color, putty

Для работы с серверами использую стандартный putty клиент или его обертку SuperPutty. 
Для putty есть различные темы - цвет фона, текстов.

Но если меня интересуют более расширеные профили - выделение слов 
memory, oracle, postgre, etc ...

возможно ли это сделать только темой для putty?

Или нужен еще и профиль на стороне сервера?

Comment: Где вы встречаеете эти слова?  cat config |  grep memory подсветит

Comment: К примеру в выводе ps -afe . Использую или не использую grep хочу что бы было выделение.

Answer (score 1):

Этим занимается не эмулятор терминала, а командная оболочка (интерпретатор команд), например, подсвечивать слова по шаблону умеет оболочка zsh с плагином [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/blob/master/docs/highlighters/pattern.md)

У функции довольно много настроек, в частности, выделение зависит от контекста и т.д., лучше всего посмотреть в мануале:
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Character-Highlighting

Без плагинов выделять произвольные слова после соответствующей настройки может оболочка fish

Другие средства (например, [grc](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html)) перечислены в статье ArchLinux wiki:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_output_in_console#Universal_wrappers

Советую также этот англоязычный ответ:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318792/218945